# How can I have multiple node applications on nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, node-modules, pugixml

I am trying to merge two (or more) nodejs apps. 1st is login application that takes you to your dashboard. When you are there you should see another app that is dedicated to you, that runs on different local IP and port.
So for login I am using  Okta express login portal that grabs user data from Okta servers. Now this is dashboard in pug

```
block content
h2.text-center Dashboard
h2.user.profile.profileUrl

.row
.offset-sm-2.col-sm-8
  .jumbotron.text-center.
    Welcome to your dashboard page, #{user.profile.firstName}.
    #{user.profile.profileUrl}.
```

and looks like this

[dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBZDQ.png)

now I want that user.profle.profileURL actually opens when clicked on control panel but address not to be visible in browser so address would be same xydomain/dashboard
is it that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

The technology you want is node js reverse proxy. You want to create multiple server on same machine or different machine, but with same domain, but after the domain extension, the different url points to different server.

If multiple server on same local machine, use different port numbers! If different machines, use the ip number of the machine and its port number. Make sure firewalls are open for the ports!

Here's a reference for you to get you started: https://codeforgeek.com/reverse-proxy-using-expressjs/

Basic understanding is create the 3 different servers. For same machine, use different port numbers.

Then create a server and get that pointing to the different servers when the url is hit.

On all servers, run this command to setup node:

npm init -y

npm i -S express http-proxy

These are the codes for all 4 servers.

eg server1:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.get('/app1',function(req,res) {
    res.send("Hello world From Server 1");
});
app.listen(3001);
```

server2:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.get('/app2',function(req,res) {
    res.send("Hello world From Server 1");
});
app.listen(3002);
```

Server3:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.get('/app3',function(req,res) {
    res.send("Hello world From Server 1");
});
app.listen(3003);
```

Reverse Proxy Server:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var serverOne = 'http://localhost:3001',
    ServerTwo = 'http://localhost:3002',
    ServerThree = 'http://localhost:3003';

app.all("/app1/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server1');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});

app.all("/app2/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server2');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: ServerTwo});
});

app.all("/app3/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server3');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: ServerThree});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Now run ALL 4 servers.

Now go to url, type in:

localhost:3000/app1/ and it goes to your server 1

localhost:3000/app2/ and it goes to your server 2

localhost:3000/app3/ and it goes to your server 3

If you're on different local machine, change localhost to the ip numbers.

If you don't like using the / after app1, then you need to configure it. This is outside the scope of this question.

Good luck to you.

Edit: I forgot to mention, your original pug file you put into your reverse proxy server. It's homepage, you render your dashboard page in your proxy server.

Comment: no thats not really solution, I am aware of  reverse proxy but then with every new server I would need manually add it to server.js and also users authentication issue, users would be able to access servers. For example user1 can go to 1,2,3,n server or each server would need separate authentication. Way that I try achieve is that server lPs are stored in db or 3rd party location and that location is called from dashboard.js I can call it but like in picture comes back as text or href link. I want that loads in dashboard pug,sort of iframe but not as access will be authorized withcookie

Comment: Your main server can run as normal, and if they go to a url it points to another server using http-proxy. Authentication - set all your servers to use  same authentication database. You can also store the server ip in database, then when Users land on main server, it calls the database, load the data to a variable and uses your server ip and point it to the servers you need.